# How I can translate this very unsafe query to a Knex querybuilder call?

Tags: node.js, sqlite, knex.js

I started with a query call like this:

```
const query = "SELECT MAX(timeStamp), Temp FROM dataTable WHERE sensorid = " + req.params.id + ";"
```

After using the docs and cheat sheet, I have something like this:

```
const query = knex("dataTable").where({'sensorid': req.params.id}).max('timeStamp').first()
```

But when I `console.log(query)` I am getting stuff that I wasn't expecting

Comment: could you add links to the docs/cheat sheet and what you're `console.log()` is giving you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Knex returns a **Promise**, so you need to `await` it.

It should look like this:

```js
const query = await knex('dataTable')
  .max('timeStamp')
  .where({ sensorid: req.params.id })
  .first();
```

Comment: Amazing. Thank you! Does Knex automatically sanitize the user input in the req.params.id field?